# How to store multiple return values in table

Tags: lua

I am trying to store multiple return values in a table. GetStatus() is a function that will return 2 values.

The bug reporter says '=' is expected near ','. I think this happens because commas are used for separating elements in a table.

How do I solve this? Thank you!

My code is following:

```
    local status = {
        ["a"],["b"] = GetStatus();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table constructor doesn't actually support multiple assigns like that. Create the table first and then assign it after

```
local status = {}
status.a, status.b = GetStatus()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create and assign a table directly from multiple return values like this:

status = table.pack(GetStatus())

This will put the results in status[1], status[2] etc.

If you need strings as key, you will have to use:

t = table.pack(GetStatus())
status = { ['a'] = t[1], ['b'] = t[2] }

Comment: Thank you. I just start to use Lua. I am confused with table.method and table[key]. I know they are different things. But why do we use one instead of another in some circumstances?